# Jekyll if statement and limit

Tags: jekyll

can i use limit parameter in if statement? 
My piece of code:

```
{% for item in site.data.events %}
<section>
  <h2 class="section-heading">{{item.date}}</h2>

  <div class="event">
    <div class="event__thumbnail-container">
      <img class="event__thumbnail" {% if item.event.section == 'Somethink' %}
```

And i try make this

```
      <img class="event__thumbnail" {% if item.event.section == 'Somethink' limit:1%}
```

Comment: Short answer : no, you can only use `limit` with `for` an `tablerow` iteration tags.
But if you elaborate a little more about conditions and desired output, maybe someone can point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you want the first item of an array, like I suspect, you are looking for the [`first`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/first/) filter